# Reading two-column data with read.table results in three columns

Tags: r, file, dataframe

I am using `read.table()` to get data from a web page. The data table has two columns and is from NIST. Following is my code, including the URL if you want to preview the data:

```r
    options(digits = 12)
    theURL <- "https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/anova/AtmWtAg.dat"
    AgData <- read.table(theURL, header = TRUE , skip = 59)
    # Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, :
    # line 1 did not have 3 elements
    AgData$Instrument = as.factor(AgData$Instrument)
    fitAgData = aov(AgWt ~ Instrument, data=AgData)
```

I have inserted the error message as a comment in the code where it occurs.

Other answers on stack exchange seem to deal with missing values causing this error. The data on this site is complete, so I'm not sure what is causing the error.

So far, I have fiddled with the `skip =` value; inserted the column names as a `read.table` argument; and added `fill = TRUE` to `read.table` The latter one resulted in a data table with three columns, one containing `NA` values. Since there are names in the table,  I have the `header=TRUE` argument on.

Somehow `read.table()` thinks there are three columns, and I don't see a way to tell it there are two.

After the skipped rows, I saw the start of the file like this:

```
Data:  
      Instrument           AgWt
          1            107.8681568
          1            107.8681465
          1            107.8681572
          1            107.8681785
```

In fact, the data looks like this:

```
Data:  Instrument           AgWt
           1            107.8681568
           1            107.8681465
           1            107.8681572
           1            107.8681785
```

Comment: It probably thinks "Data:" is the name of your first column. So it scans that line and identifies 3 columns, then gets to the data and only sees 2. Try skipping that line and then manually naming your data.

Comment: @Adam: That's the answer. When I read it, I somehow saw 'Data:' on a line by itself. If you'll enter your comment as an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It identifies "Data:" as the name of your first column. So it scans the header and identifies 3 columns, then gets to the data and only sees 2. Try skipping that line and then manually naming your data.